# CSS : Fixing up/down arrow CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

I never worked with CSS, By clicking the  element the arrow-up and arrow down gets toggled, but the css has some issue, this I want to fix:
The arrow should look like as in the table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_foreign-born_population

Class names can be given/modified.

```
<span class="arrows">
    <span ng-hide="field == 'name'  order" class="arrow-down"></span>
    <span ng-hide="field == 'name' && !order" class="arrow-up"></span>
</span>
```

Js fiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/vyy883Lp/4/

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was quite alot wrong with the code:
Note: you can check compiler errors by opening chrome developer tools (or whatever browser you use) - and it alerts you with a stack trace

- Angular module wasn't declared
- Errors in directives needed fixing -
- and `arrow` (chevron) elements needed to be brought `inline` with each other
- `arrow` elements need to be `block` - so they stacked
- and also ....

#### Logic in code needed to be changed

In my code, when `up` and `down` CSS classes are applied BOTH arrows show.
To apply CSS classes, the values in the `ng-class` objects needs to be true.
In order to get the toggle effect, they have to be positioned opposite to each other and then set to cycle whenever ng-click is used.
BUT they BOTH need to start out **on** so I have added the `clean` variable and an `OR` switch inside `ng-class` to make sure the CSS classes are applied when the page first loads.

Here is a working **demo** - similar to the wikipedia page you linked to
.
http://jsbin.com/wequmipide/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Set the display-type of the arrow-spans to inline-block. This means you can modify size, margin, ... but the elements stay in the text-flow. I would suggest a text-align: middle - it looks much cleaner this way.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zy9468LL/

```
.arrow-up {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        vertical-align:middle;
        border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    }
```

Also, remove the wrapper-element (span class "arrows") and set only one span with a dynamic class.

```
<span class="{'arrow-up' : field == 'name' && !order, 'arrow-down' : field == 'name' && order }"></span>
```

Comment: It should show both the error when that field is not the sorting key.